# Unable to create new java project in Eclipse 3.6.1

Tags: java, eclipse

I am unable to create a "new Java Project" in Eclipse 3.6.1? I am using Linux sol24 2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64.

When I go to file and then new, I don't see new Java Project. There is just project.
Also, when I do create a new project. I am unable to access src.

Can someone offer some insight into this?

Thanks

Comment: You should add the information about only seeing "General" and "CVS" on the Wizard screen into your question.  Might help someone else help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only have "General" and "CVS", it appears that you have `Eclipse`, but don't have `Java` for it.

Please try this `Linux` command in a `terminal`.

```
apt-get install eclipse-jdt
```

This will install the necessary `Java Development Tools` for your `Eclipse`.

Make sure you run `sudo` and restart `Eclipse` after installing.

Answer (score 1):

When you click new, go to other in the list and then you will see a list of all possible things you can create. you should Java project there.

Comment: Ok. I go there and I see two folders/categories. They are "General" and "CVS." None of these two contains  "Java Project"